# RangeError: Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3 flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add text to the list when the onPressedButton is pressed. But I get the following error: RangeError: Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..2: 3 flutter

In some related answers, I confirmed that it was because 'itemCount: name.length' was not added, and I added it, but the result was the same. What is the problem?

The coding is as follows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var total = 3;
  var name = ['김영숙', '홍길동', '피자집'];
  var like = [0, 0, 0];

  addName(a) {
    setState(() {
      name.add(a);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text(total.toString()),
        onPressed: () {
          print(context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<MaterialApp>());
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return DialogUI(addName: addName);
              });
        },
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(total.toString()),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: name.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Text(like[i].toString()),
            title: Text(name[i]),
            trailing: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                primary: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: Text('좋아요'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  like[i]++;
                });
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BtmBar(),
    );
  }
}

class DialogUI extends StatelessWidget {
  DialogUI({Key? key, this.addName}) : super(key: key);
  final addName;
  var inputData = TextEditingController();
  var inputData2 = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: inputData,
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                addName(inputData.text);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BtmBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BtmBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.phone),
          Icon(Icons.message),
          Icon(Icons.access_alarms),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RangeError comes up when we try to access the member of an array(here list) that doesn't exist.
Here, please check while accessing the members of `name` & `like` at a particular index do exist.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you make `name` grow but not `like`

So you need to do

```
addName(a) {
  setState(() {
    name.add(a);
    like.add(0);
  });
}
```

so new names also have an entry for likes.

another tip is to just remove `total` and where you use `total.toString()` use `name.length.toString()` instead so that also shows the correct amount at all times